# Extracting a particular row from a 3D matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a 3D matrix u(151,1001,2001) and I need a particular row extracted from it (let's say (51,1,:) in a form of a vector so I could plot it as a time series.

Is there any way that could be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Matlab function for that called `squeeze` ([web](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html)) that

> returns an array B with the same elements as A, but with all singleton dimensions removed.

when computing

```
B = squeeze(A)
```

In your case,

```
v = squeeze(u(51,1,:));
```

Comment: That's where the mistake was then. I used the variable instead of the colon in the squeeze part. And it just gave me nothing when I plotted it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped - and don't forget to upvote the answers that were useful to you. Welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

To convert anything to a column vector, you can use `(:)` in matlab:

```
v=u(51,1,:);
v=v(:);
```

Alternatives to solve this problem are `reshape` and `permute`, two functions you will probably need when you proceed with 3D-Matrices.